# trying to open the sdcard's .txt file in my EditText

Tags: android

I am trying to open the sdcard's .txt file in my `EditText` to change the text in it and
save the changes using button click but its not going in right way .May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Comment: i am new in android. i try to learn by developer console but did not get anything about editing the text file in android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            try this one..

you must set permission in the manifest file:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  


         File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()                          + "followed by ur file dir");

         File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()                          + "sdcard.txt");

          for (File wavfile : f.listFiles())
         {
            String str = wavfile.getName().toString();   
         StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();    
                        String aDataRow = "";  
                        String aBuffer = "";  
                        try {  
                            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/"+filename);  
                            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);  
                            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(  
                                    new InputStreamReader(fIn));  

                            while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {  
                                aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";  
                            }  
                            myReader.close();  
        edtitext.setText(aBuffer.tostring());

                        } catch (IOException e) {  
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }  
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext  

        (),aBuffer,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

                    }       
        }
        again btnclick you have to write that edited string right..



        use this one for write in that file..
        FileOutputStream fos;  
                           try {  
                               File myFile = new File("/sdcard/"+sdcard.txt);  
                                myFile.createNewFile();  
                                FileOutputStream fOut = new   

        FileOutputStream(myFile);  
                                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new   

        OutputStreamWriter(fOut);  
                                myOutWriter.append(data);  
                                myOutWriter.close();  
                                fOut.close();  

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),filename + "   

        saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  


                           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
                           catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  

                    }   

    thank you...


    more detalis ref this link'

    http://www.javatpoint.com/android-external-storage-example
    ----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Some manufacturers (mainly Samsung) give write permissions only to the internal storage mounted at `/storage/sdcard`.

Also you should enable your app to write to external storage by adding this permission in the manifest:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score -1):

First try to read the complete text file and save the text in a string.

For that you can refer this [link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523)

When you read the complete text file and get the text in a string, set the string to the editText by

```
edtitext.setText(your string);
```